# URF with WPF MVVM Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, unit-of-work

I'm using this framework: [URF](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com) and [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.com/) to create a business WPF application.

This is the code for the CM bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private SimpleContainer container;

    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = new SimpleContainer();

        container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();

        container.PerRequest<IShell, ShellViewModel>();
        container.AllTypesOf<ITabItem>(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        container.PerRequest<IDataContextAsync, AuraContext>();
        container.PerRequest<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork>();
        container.PerRequest<IRepositoryAsync<Audit>, Repository<Audit>>();
        container.PerRequest<IAuditService, AuditService>();
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        var instance = container.GetInstance(service, key);
        if (instance != null)
            return instance;

        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Could not locate any instances of type {0}", service.Name));
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        return container.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        container.BuildUp(instance);
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
    }
}
```

The ShellViewModel.cs code:

```
public class ShellViewModel: Conductor<ITabItem>.Collection.OneActive, IShell
{
    private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ShellViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager, IEnumerable<ITabItem> tabItems)
    {
        DisplayName = "Aura";

        _windowManager = windowManager;

        Items.AddRange(tabItems.Where(t => t.IsEnabled).OrderBy(t => t.DisplayOrder));
    }
}
```

The ShellView.xaml markup:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Aura.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Aura"               
             mc:Ignorable="d"       
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600" MinWidth="800" MinHeight="600">

    <TabControl x:Name="Items" Margin="3">

</UserControl>
```

This is some Repository:

```
public static class AuditRepository
{
    public static async Task<Audit> GetCurrentAudit(this IRepositoryAsync<Audit> repository)
    {
        var audits = await repository
                .Query(a => a.BeginDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
                .Include()
                .SelectAsync(); ;

        return audits.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Reminder> GetRemindersForAudit(this IRepositoryAsync<Audit> repository, int auditId)
    {
        var audits = repository.GetRepository<Audit>().Queryable();
        var phases = repository.GetRepository<Phase>().Queryable();
        var reminders = repository.GetRepository<Reminder>().Queryable();

        var query = from audit in audits
                    where audit.Id == auditId
                        join phase in phases on audit.Id equals phase.AuditId
                        join reminder in reminders on phase.Id equals reminder.PhaseId
                    select reminder;

        return query.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

And its Service:

```
public interface IAuditService: IService<Audit>
{
    Task<Audit> GetCurrentAudit();
}

public class AuditService: Service<Audit>, IAuditService
{
    private readonly IRepositoryAsync<Audit> _repository;

    public AuditService(IRepositoryAsync<Audit> repository)
        :base(repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<Audit> GetCurrentAudit()
    {
        return await _repository.GetCurrentAudit();
    }

    public override void Delete(Audit entity)
    {
        // business logic here
        base.Delete(entity);
    }

    public override void Update(Audit entity)
    {
        // business logic here
        base.Update(entity);
    }

    public override void Insert(Audit entity)
    {
        // business logic here
        base.Insert(entity);
    }
}
```

This is my ViewModels constructor:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public AdminViewModel(
    IWindowManager windowManager,
    IEventAggregator eventAggregator,
    IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWorkAsync,
    IAuditService auditService)
{
    _windowManager = windowManager;
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    _unitOfWorkAsync = unitOfWorkAsync;
    _auditService = auditService
}
```

And the implementation in that ViewModel that's giving me issues:

```
try
{

    //var audits = await _unitOfWorkAsync.RepositoryAsync<Audit>().Query().SelectAsync();

    //Audits = new ObservableCollection<Audit>(audits);
    SelectedAudit = await _auditService.GetCurrentAudit();
    //AuditHistoryHeader = String.Format(Constants.ADMINVIEW_AUDITHISTORYHEADER, Audits.Count);

    SelectedAudit.ObjectState = ObjectState.Deleted;
    _auditService.Delete(SelectedAudit);
    _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChanges();

    var audit = _unitOfWorkAsync.Repository<Audit>().Query().Select().FirstOrDefault();

    _unitOfWorkAsync.Repository<Audit>().Delete(audit);
    _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChanges();


}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Something I'm not sure of in the [URF](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com) **UnitOfWork.cs** file:

```
public IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : Entity, IEntity
{
    try
    {
        if (ServiceLocator.IsLocationProviderSet)
        //if (ServiceLocator.Current != null)
        //{
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository<TEntity>>();
        //}
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }

    return RepositoryAsync<TEntity>();
    //return IoC.Get<IRepositoryAsync<TEntity>>();
}
```

The problem is that the only way to persist CRUD operations to the database is with the _unitOfWorkAsync.Repository() object and not using the service.
That does not fail but no changes in the DB.. I'm a bit unsure about the `ServiceLocator` used in [URF](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com) and the `SimpleContainer` from [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.com/) and how they (should) work together. I'm also unsure about the *LifeTime* of the containers objects in the `Bootstrapper.cs` file.

I'm just starting to understand the DI pattern but I think this is what is giving me the issue I'm having..

If someone already did something like this or sees what the problem is, please let me know. If you like to see more code, please comment below.

**EDIT:**

I've tried the following but the data is not being deleted..

```
try
{
    SelectedAudit = await _auditService.GetCurrentAudit();
    SelectedAudit.ObjectState = ObjectState.Deleted;

    _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

If I step into the UnitOfWork.cs `SaveChanges` and look into the `IDataContextAsync _dataContext` Audits dbSet the Audit has ObjectState `Unchanged`. So the deleted Audit is not part of that context?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for your DI setup, as I've never used SimpleContainer (I'm using URF with Autofac). The code in URF you are unsure of is fine. Works great with Autofac and Ninject so I'm guessing SimpleContainer will be similar. But one problem I see is in the following lines of code:

```
SelectedAudit = await _auditService.GetCurrentAudit();
//AuditHistoryHeader = String.Format(Constants.ADMINVIEW_AUDITHISTORYHEADER, Audits.Count);

SelectedAudit.ObjectState = ObjectState.Deleted;
_auditService.Delete(SelectedAudit); // <-- This is a problem
_unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChanges();
```

First, you get the SelectedAudit. SelectedAudit now being tracked by entity framework. You then set the state of SelectedAudit to deleted. So far so good. All you have to do now is call Savechanges. SelectedAudit is already attached to you entity framework context and marking it's state as deleted is enough for entity framework to know to delete it. Calling Delete from your service will try attach the SelectedAudit to the context again. This will either throw an exception (most likely) or cause undesired behaviour. If you remove the line

```
_auditService.Delete(SelectedAudit);
```

it should work. Note this is the same for updates to an entity. Get the entity, make changes to it then call SaveChanges WITHOUT calling your service update method.

You should only uses the update/delete methods if you DON'T get the entity first within the same context.

As for lifetime management, default URF uses PerRequest for IDataContextAsync, IUnitOfWorkAsync and INorthwindStoredProcedures. The rest all use TransientLifetime. Stick with that and change if you need to.

EXTRA INFO
I've modified my service to accept viewmodels instead of entities. This is the service I use. I like this better as it keeps better separation (IMO) between the DAL and Web layers.

```
public interface IService<TModel>
{
    TModel Find(params object[] keyValues);
    Task<TModel> Insert(TModel model);
    IEnumerable<TModel> InsertRange(IEnumerable<TModel> models);
    Task<TModel> Update(TModel model);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Delete(TModel model);
    Task<TModel> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues);
    Task<TModel> FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues);
    Task<bool> DeleteAsync(params object[] keyValues);
    Task<bool> DeleteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues);
}

public abstract class Service<TModel, TEntity> : IService<TModel> where TEntity : class, IObjectState
{
    #region Private Fields

    private readonly IRepositoryAsync<TEntity> _repository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    #endregion Private Fields

    #region Constructor

    protected Service(IRepositoryAsync<TEntity> repository, IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    #endregion Constructor

    public void Delete(TModel model)
    {
        _unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<TEntity>().Delete(_mapper.Map<TEntity>(model));
        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(object id)
    {
        _unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<TEntity>().Delete(id);
        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        return await DeleteAsync(CancellationToken.None, keyValues);
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues)
    {
        var result = await _unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<TEntity>().DeleteAsync(cancellationToken, keyValues);
        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        return result;
    }

    public TModel Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        return _mapper.Map<TModel>(_repository.Find(keyValues));
    }

    public async Task<TModel> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        var entity = await _repository.FindAsync(keyValues);
        return _mapper.Map<TModel>(entity);
    }

    public async Task<TModel> FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues)
    {
        var entity = await _repository.FindAsync(cancellationToken, keyValues);
        return _mapper.Map<TModel>(entity);
    }

    public async Task<TModel> Insert(TModel model)
    {
        var entity = _unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<TEntity>().Insert(_mapper.Map<TEntity>(model));
        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        return _mapper.Map<TModel>(entity);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TModel> InsertRange(IEnumerable<TModel> models)
    {
        var entities = _unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<TEntity>().InsertRange(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TEntity>>(models));
        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TModel>>(entities);
    }

    public async Task<TModel> Update(TModel model)
    {
        var entity = _unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<TEntity>().Update(_mapper.Map<TEntity>(model));
        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        return _mapper.Map<TModel>(entity);
    }

    public async Task<TModel> UpdateFieldsOnly(TModel model, params string[] fields)
    {
        var entity = _unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<TEntity>().UpdateFieldsOnly(_mapper.Map<TEntity>(model), fields);
        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        return _mapper.Map<TModel>(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi garethb, thanks for your answer. I'll try this when I'm at work in about 1 hour. But I'm a bit unsure of an update method on the service if I can't pass an existing entity. How do you go about that?

Comment: I usually pass the viewmodel to my service. From my service, I get the entity and map the viewmodel to the entity, something like this in my service. var entity = _repository.Find(viewmodel.Id); entity.FirstName = viewmodel.FirstName; entity.ObjectState = ObjectState.Modified; _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

Comment: See updated answer for my modified service. Note I am using Automapper to map between my models and entities but you can map manually as well.

Comment: Hi gartehb, thanks for the extra code! :) But I edited my question. The delete is still not being persisted to the database. :( Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try without using async. Also, I read update as the issue for some reason and not delete! Sorry about that. Once you set the ObjectState to deleted, you should call _service.Delete(entity). If that doesn't work, try _service.Delete(entity.Id).

Comment: Hi garethb, I noticed you have private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync _unitOfWork; in your service but I don't see this anywhere in the original URF source code :) Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, I've moved the unit of work stuff out of my controllers and into my services. In the original URF, you will find that bit of code in the controllers. For instance see Northwind.Web.Api.CustomerController. It's just the dependency injection of the unit of work into my services.

Comment: Thank you gareth, I'll try it this way!

Comment: Why are you using _unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<TEntity>() one time and the other time _repository.Find(keyValues)? Using the _unitOfWork repository works fine but I don't understand _repository use?

Comment: My main question (if you look at the Norhtwind.Web.Api.CustomerController) is how the code in the controller works. You call the service and then the unitOfWork save but I don't get it to work this way...

Comment: The way I see it, using _unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<TEntity>() is mainly for when you are accessing multiple repositories within the same unitOfWork. TBH I prefer using that more than just _repository. Might change it. Are you getting any errors? Maybe try calling 'await _unitOfOwrk.SaveChangesAsync()'. Also, set you breakpoint on the savechanges and follow it through to SyncObjectsStatePreCommit(). Does it change the state of your deleted entity there?

Comment: Also check the state is being changed correctly after you call Delete in DataContext SyncObjectState()

Comment: You've been a big help. I've got it running. Maybe not totally as intended by the framework but it works. I'll update my answer later today. Maybe we can share experiences?

Comment: Looking forward to the update! Interesting to see why it wasn't working!